# What does *(double*)&a do?

Tags: c++, type-punning

What is the purpose of (double*) here?
I understand that:

```
double d1 = *&a;
```

Will give me the value at the address of a, but adding the (double*) stores the value 1.4854e-313 into d1. Why is this? What is type punning? Also, have I written or read from unalocated memory??

```
int main () {
    int a = 17;
    double d1 = *(double*)&a ;
    std :: cout << "\na = " << a << ", &a = " << & a ;
    std :: cout << "\nd1 = " << d1 << ", &d1 = " << & d1 ;
}
```

Comment: HINT: What is the length (in bytes) of an int? What about a double? If you try to read the memory where an int lies, but you read a double from it, can you guarantee you'll only be reading your own memory?

Comment: Undefined behaviour, `a` is not a double

Comment: *"What is type punning?"* Interpreting memory representation of an object as if was an object of a different type. In most cases it's UB.

Answer (score 2):

This is type punning, but it's also undefined behavior. `int` does not have the same size as `double` on most platforms, which means that casting an `int` pointer to a `double` pointer, and then reading from it, will read from stack data you shouldn't have access to.

What is happening, literally, is that `d1` is being assigned the bits stored at and around `a`. Because these bits are arbitrary (and probably read garbage from the stack), its value could be just about anything.

It should go without saying that you shouldn't do this. Type-Punning is only barely defined behavior under ideal circumstances, and definitely not using the method you're using here.

Comment: It's equivalent to `d1 = reinterpret_cast<double>(a)`, right?

Comment: @Barmar no, for several reasons, the biggest being that it wouldn't compile (to prevent exactly this).

Comment: Even if the sizes were the same, this would be UB because it breaks the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @Barmar more like `d1 = reinterpret_cast<double&>(a)` instead. The reference is important. The *address* of `a` is interpreted as if it were the *address* of a `double`, and then a `double` is read from that address. Without the reference, the *value* of `a` is interpreted as if it were a `double`, which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening here is you are recasting `a`, which is an `int`, forcibly to a `double`.

Let me break it down:

`&a` gets the pointer of type `int *` to the variable `a`.

Then, with `(double *)` you are recasting this pointer to type `double *`.

Finally, with the `*` you are dereferencing the casted pointer to a `double`.

So, all together, you're taking the pointer to `a`, recasting it as `double*`, dereferencing it, and assigning the value to the variable `d1`.

This is known as type-punning, and as other people have mentioned, it is bad because the two types `int` and `double` likely take up different number of bytes in memory.

Let's assume that `int` is defined as 4 bytes on your system, and `double` is 8 bytes. Then it's a problem because you're telling your system "hey, look, you can read the next 8 bytes at this address, instead of the 4 bytes that are actually valid data." Who knows what is in those next 4 bytes? The behavior is *undefined*, and you're basically guaranteed to read garbage.

Comment: Even if the sizes are the same, type punning is normally undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It does similar as in the code below. It also has UB if it assigns `int` and gets `double`, but it does not accesses alien memory and does not break the strict aliasing at least.

```
union mixed_types {
    int a;
    double d1;
};

int main () {
    mixed_types bad;
    bad.a = 17;
    double d1 = bad.d;
    std :: cout << "\na = " << a << ", &a = " << & a ;
    std :: cout << "\nd1 = " << d1 << ", &d1 = " << & d1 ;
}
```